# TapGesture segue works to view, but not view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, segue

I have a RootViewController with a UITableView that segues(push) to a DetailViewController. Using a tapGestureRecognizer in DetailViewController, it segues back(push) to the RootViewController.

A few days ago the segue back to the RootViewController was working fine when the tapGestureRecognizer was set to segue to the RootViewController View, not the RootViewController itself. Somewhere along the lines, I changed the segue to land at the RootViewController itself and now the segue back is not working. For some reason, xcode will not let me ctrl + drag from the tapRecognizer to the RootViewController View, only the RootViewController. I'm almost positive it will work if I'm able to drag to the View.

Any ideas of why I wouldn't be able to ctrl + drag to the View all of a sudden?

Comment: You never were able to ctrl-drag to the View. A segue puts a new `ViewController` on screen. That's the whole point of storyboards. Each `ViewController` is a "scene". Segues move you from one scene to another. Are you trying to do anything in code or just on the storyboard?

Comment: Just storyboard. It's just weird that is was working for me and all of a sudden stopped.

Comment: I figured it out. Answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I needed to connect `gestureRecognizers` to `View`in Referencing Outlet Collections.